# Drawing line after object while using jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-animate

I'm having this square which is animated to a random position every 5th second. What I now want to do is to draw a line after the square when it's moving, so I can se where it has been and so on. Any ideas how i should do this? Very greatful for help, thanks!

```
<div id="square" style="width:50px; height:50px; background:blue; position:relative;"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){

    var posx = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
    var posy = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);

  $('#square').animate({ left:(posx*1), top: (posy*1) }, 3000);  

 },5000);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. It's not pretty, but should get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/9gcXN/

HTML

```
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="mycanvas" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
<div id="square" style="width:50px; height:50px; background:blue; position: absolute;"></div>
```

JS

```
canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

$(document).ready(function() {
var posx,posy,lastx,lasty = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
    lastx = posx;
    lasty = posy;

    posx = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    posy = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);

        $('#square').animate({ left:(posx*1), top: (posy*1) }, 3000, function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(lastx,lasty);
ctx.lineTo(posx,posy);
ctx.stroke();

        });  

},3000);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this will help alot! @MagnusEngdal

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [step function for jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){

```
var posx = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);
var posy = Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);

  $('#square').animate({ left:(posx*1), top: (posy*1) }, {
      duration: 3000,
      step: function (now, tween) {
          var elemOffset = $(tween.elem).offset();
          $('<div class="a"></div>').css({top: elemOffset.top, left: elemOffset.left}).appendTo('body');
      }
  });
```

},5000);
});

My example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g7xGy/